# Change default UIDatePicker and enable it to accept 00 as day and month. like this 00-00-YYYY

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

I wanted to change my default UIDatePicker functionality and want to enable it to accept 00 as a valid day and month like this 00-00-YYYY. Please view the attached image to see current implementation. Is it possible? Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.
[image]

Comment: you can create your own picker and provide the your customized data./

Comment: Since `UIDatePicker` works with instances of `NSDate` and `NSCalendar` I think that you have to subclass `NSCalendar` to insert "empty" values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create your own data set and use a UIPickerView to display the values. Trying to bend the date picker into doing something nonstandard like that could create a lot of side-effects and also break in future releases. Creating your own picker items is a much safer and cleaner way!

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about the same solution but was wondering if there might be another way to implement it. But i guess, as you said, creating my own picker would be a much safer and better approach. Thanks again for your assistance.